# C++ - Combing Transforms Without Matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, transform, glm-math

This seems like a fairly simple problem, yet somehow I have still failed to get it right. I have sets of transform information, as defined in the following class:

```
class Transform {
public:

    glm::vec2 Translate;
    float Rotate;           // About AnchorPoint
    glm::vec2 Scale;        // About AnchorPoint
    glm::vec2 AnchorPoint;

    // ... member funcs, etc
};
```

I'm now trying to write `operator*(Transform T1, Transform T2)`, which is supposed to combine these tranforms (as if one was applied after the other.) For instance, with matrices, we'd simply use:

`return T1.GetMatrix() * T2.GetMatrix();`

And this would return a matrix where both transforms are applied (in reverse order). I'm essentially trying to do the same thing, but while keeping the separated translation, rotation, scale and anchor point components. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
Transform operator*(Transform &T1, Transform &T2) {
    return Transform(
        T1.Translate + T1.Scale * glm::vec2(T2.Translate.x * cos(Radians(T1.Rotate)) - T2.Translate.y 
            * sin(Radians(T1.Rotate)),
            T2.Translate.x * sin(Radians(T1.Rotate)) + T2.Translate.y * cos(Radians(T1.Rotate))),
        T1.Rotate + T2.Rotate,
        T1.Scale * T2.Scale,
        T1.AnchorPoint
    );
}
```

I can't pinpoint what's going wrong with this but something clearly is, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Surely `T2.AnchorPoint` should have an influence and not just be outright discarded?

Comment: My approach would be to write out both transforms as matrices (with 7 variables each), multiply them by hand and then extract the terms you need for your code. Beware, it'll probably look heinous. But it'll be correct.

Comment: I think that this cannot be done with this generally. You'll need a `Shear` member as well: a rotate, scale, rotate sequence can produce any 2x2 matrix, and yet you only have 3 parameters (`Rotate`: 1 parameter and `Scale`: 2 parameters) to describe it. And `AnchorPoint` is redundant, there is no need for it.